# Filter using a "Scripted fields" in a Kibana dashboard

Tags: date, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I create dashboards under Kibana.
I wanted to plot my graphs according to the date but I only had a "date" parameter in integer. This "date" parameter represents the date in the form of milliseconds.
To remedy this I created a scripted fields "DATE_ISO" in date format by doing:
doc['date'].value

My graphs appear fine with the DATE_ISO on the x axis but when I try to filter this parameter it doesn't work.

The "date" parameter (in milliseconds) can be filtered but not the DATE_ISO.

Can you help me ?

I tried several date formats such as:
2001-01-01 13:00:00 or Nov 24, 2022 @ 11:05:36.978 or 2001/01/01
But it does not work.
It also doesn't work when I enter "last 30 days" in the filter.

Comment: The `kql` tag is dedicated for Kusto Query Language

Comment: which version of elasticsearch are you using? can you share an example value?